# Length of all string in the list: the fastest way

Tags: python, performance

I'm trying:

```
python3 -m timeit -c 'len("".join([str(x) for x in range(0, 999999)]))'
10 loops, best of 3: 330 msec per loop

python3 -m timeit -c 'sum((len(y) for y in [str(x) for x in range(0, 999999)]))
10 loops, best of 3: 439 msec per loop
```

Why does this happen? Is there a faster way?

P.S. It is assumed that a list of strings will be in advance.

Comment: Try `sum(map(len, map(str, range(999999))))`, it will probbly be faster.  But who cares, really ..

Comment: @wim I just benchmarked with a pre-built list, and your suggestion is still three times slower than `join` + `len`.

Comment: You're concatenating many small strings to a huge string, you should rather count the length of each small string, that would be quicker. Also, if you wanna know how many digits there's in a number, there are better ways.

Comment: Oh, I was timing on python 2 not python 3 - where it was faster than both.  _Edit:_  it seems to still be faster than both on python 3 for me.  Odd

Comment: How about `sum([len(str(x)) for x in range(999999)])`? I would guess it to come out just slightly faster than your 2nd option.

Comment: `len(''.join(map(str, range(999999))))` was faster again

Comment: @EranZimmerman you are right, it will be faster.
I did so for a fair comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better benchmark with IPython shows the situation is worse than you thought:

```
>>> lst = [str(x) for x in range(0, 999999)]
>>> %timeit len("".join(lst))
100 loops, best of 3: 9.94 ms per loop
>>> %timeit sum(len(x) for x in lst)
10 loops, best of 3: 62.2 ms per loop
```

You're seeing two effects here, the overhead of function calls in Python and the overhead of its iteration. `"".join` doesn't have either because it's a single method call that does a loop in C. Intermediate performance with less memory use can be gotten from `map`:

```
>>> %timeit sum(map(len, lst))
10 loops, best of 3: 29.4 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 7):

Ignoring that rather small time difference for now, there is actually a huge difference for your two ways *in memory*.

```
sum((len(y) for y in [str(x) for x in range(0, 999999)]))
```

This will create a string for each number and store that in a list. Then you use a generator expression to loop over that list and sum the lengths up. So you essentially have a string for each number, a list storing all strings, and a number that is being added to for the lengths.

```
len(''.join([str(x) for x in range(0, 999999)]))
```

This will again create a string for each number and store that in a list. Then you create a huge string with all numbers. Afterwards you call length on in (which is then a O(1) call). So you don’t have the number you add to (while summing the lengths up), but you do have another long string that combines all the other strings again.

So even if that is faster, you are throwing away a lot of memory, which will likely have an effect on performance later too.

To improve all this, you should consider creating as little stuff permanently as possible. Don’t use list comprehensions as that will actually create the lists; don’t use `str.join` as that requires a list and iterates it twice.

```
sum(len(str(x)) for x in range(0, 999999)))
```

Now, this will still be slower than the `len(''.join(…))` method but won’t have that much of a memory overhead. In fact, it will only create one string object at a time, get its length and add it to the sum. The string can then be immediately collected.

The reason this will still be slow though is that it both `len` and `str` need to be looked up with every iteration inside of the generator. To speed that up, use `map` to only look it up twice. wim made a really good suggestion in the comments:

```
sum(map(len, map(str, range(999999))))
```

This actually performs faster than the `len(''.join(…))` way for me. My timing results in order of being mentioned in my answer:

```
62.36836282166257
50.54277449168785
58.24419845897603
40.3403849521618
```

Answer (score 2):

The first (faster) version has 1 call to the `len` function, 1 call to `join` and 100k calls to `str`. Looking at the second line you can see that both `len` and `str` are called 100k times each which makes for about twice as many total function calls in the second case.