# How can I sum values in a list?

Tags: python, list, sum

My code:

```
distance = ['0.12', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.12', '0.01', '0.13', '0.02', '0.12', '0.02', '0.12', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.12', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.01', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.01']
```

the values are from a CSV file and appending it to distance list. how do I sum them so I can get a total distance? I've tried some of the answers given on the website but they haven't worked :(

Answer (score 5):

Convert the strings to floats using `map`, and then sum the resulting numbers with `sum`.

```
>>> sum(map(float, distance))
2.9199999999999986
```

Those 9s are due to the inherent imprecision of floats. If you want something exact, you can use `Decimal`.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> sum(map(Decimal, distance))
Decimal('2.92')
```

Comment: A generator expression might be considered more Pythonic: `sum( float(x) for x in distance)`.

Comment: @chepner : why? would you replace all usage of `map` by a generator? (itertools.imap would return a generator as well, hence eliminating the creation of the list `map` returns, too)

Comment: You can use `math.fsum` instead of `sum` to get more accurate results.

Comment: @njzk2 http://stackoverflow.com/q/1247486/1126841

Comment: Using `map` (or imap) is a lot more efficient, as you are *not* interested in the resulting list. See also my answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501174/length-of-all-string-in-the-list-the-fastest-way/21501588#21501588).

Comment: Good idea, @AshwiniChaudhary. In this particular instance, `fsum` gives a result that is two decimal places more accurate. The practical difference being, it gets displayed as `2.92` when printed. (although in reality it's actually represented as `2.9199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875`)

Answer (score 4):

Convert each element to a float and use the `sum` builtin:

```
distance = ['0.12', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.12', '0.01', '0.13', '0.02', '0.12', '0.02', '0.12', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.12', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.01', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.01']

distance = [float(s) for s in distance]
total = sum(distance)

total
>>> 2.9199999999999986
```

To take care of the extra 9s, use Decimal.

```
from decimal import Decimal

distance = [Decimal(s) for s in distance]
total = sum(distance)
total
>>>Decimal('2.92')
```

Answer (score 3):

Before you use the built-in `sum` you need to convert the string values to floats.

This does not work:

```
>>> sum(['1', '2'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

But this does:

```
>>> sum([1,2])
3
```

Therefor you need to step through every value of your list `distance` and convert to a float before handing the list to `sum`.

You can use a list comprehension, map, a loop or a generator expression:

```
>>> distance = ['0.12', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.12', '0.01', '0.13', '0.02', '0.12', '0.02', '0.12', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.12', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.01', '0.13', '0.02', '0.13', '0.01']
>>> sum(float(e) for e in distance)
2.9199999999999986
```

For a more accurate result, use [fsum](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.fsum):

```
>>> math.fsum(float(e) for e in distance)
2.92
```

Comment: Technically, this is a generator expression, as no list is created as would be with `sum([float(e) for e in distance])`.